# Angular 6 effect merge payload and data from service call in a new action

Tags: angular, rxjs6, ngrx-effects

I get a payload from an action `payload: { items: Administration[], id: number}`
in an effect.

I use a service inside to post the new value and return it in an succes action.

I would like just pass the id with the result of the httpCall, but il loose the payload after the service.

I tried an `mergeMap(([action, items]) => new SuccessAction({items}))` after the  switchMap.

But don't realy understand where or how implement it, something like that,

```js
@Effect() update$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType<UpdateAction>(ActionTypes.UPDATE),
  switchMap(action => this.service.update(action.payload.items).pipe(
  map(response => response.items }), 
    catchError(error => of(new FailureAction({error}))
  ))),
  mergeMap(([action, items]) => new UpdateAction({action.payload.id, items}))
);`
```

If someone could help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

Take care about the new Rxjs standards, you are actually using pipe in pipe.
The problem is that you are using data that are losts in your pipe (the payload) you can keep it in it or you can retake the information with `withLatestFrom()`.

```
@Effect() update$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType<UpdateAction>(ActionTypes.UPDATE),
    switchMap(action => ({ payload: of(action.payload), response: this.service.update(action.payload.items)})),
    map(data => new UpdateAction({id: data.payload.id, items: data.response.items})),
    catchError(error => of(new FailureAction(error))),
);
```

I hope this will help you !